# How can I find an element in an m-sorted array, where the rest of the array is zeros and m is not given

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, search, data-structures

Given an array with n elements. The first m elements in the array are sorted (without duplicates) and different from zero. **The rest of the array is zeros.**

**It should be noted that m is not known** - it could be anything, but it is known that **n >> m**.

Now, given x; if it exists in the array, I should return its index, otherwise, it does not exist.
Now the thing is that **I have to find an algorithm that does so**.

A trivial answer would be to scan the array as long as the next element is not zero, with O(m) time complexity, or simply a modified version of "Binary Search" which would take O(logn) time complexity.
Apart from these two solutions - I have no clue. **It has been hinted that we can find x in O(log m) time complexity, by finding m in O(logm) time** Then I could do binary search on the first m elements... but otherwise I have no clue!

Comment: Your idea is the right one. Binary search in the first `m` elements is the way to go.

Comment: 'm' is unknown @m.raynal, this is the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find `m` in `O(log m)` time as follows (considering that the first `m` elements do *not* contain `0`).

```
i = 1
while A[i] != 0 do
  i = 2*i
return i
```

This gives you an upper bound on `m` that is at most `2m` (meaning `m <= i <= 2m`). All you have to do then is a binary search on the `i` first elements of your array to find `x`.

Each operation can be done in `O(log m)` time, so the total complexity is `O(log m)`.